# Kali not showing in Kali-OSX dual boot on Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, unix, dual-boot

**Some context:**

- I have a Macbook Pro with OSX Mojave
- I installed Kali Linux
- Boot defaulted to Kali
- If I wanted to boot OSX I had to hold down the option key on boot.
- When selecting boot drives, Kali never showed up; only OSX.
- Today boot defaulted to OSX
- Kali still doesn't appear even though it's installed.

**My question:** How can I boot Kali now that boot defaults to OSX?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this blog post](https://mattkoskela.com/tech/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-on-a-macbook-pro/), I was able to solve this issue using rEFInd.

Basically, rEFInd is a tool that allows you to select what operating system you want to boot with.

- You can download rEFInd here: [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/)
- Full rEFInd documentation here: [link](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

Comment: This would be a much more useful answer if you told us how you used rEFInd to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how a user can actually go about this. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.